# AngularJs Cache not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, caching, microsoft-edge

I'm using angular-cache.

```
angularApp.service('MyCache', function (CacheFactory) {
this.getCacheObject = function () {
    var mycache = CacheFactory('MyCacheObj', {
        maxAge:20 * 60 * 1000, cacheFlushInterval:20 * 60 * 1000, deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive'
    });
    return mycache;
}});
```

Cache is working fine in chrome but is not in working in IE and EDGE browser. 
Every time I move from one page to another(not refresh) the $http calls  in the page are cached in chrome browser but not in IE and EDGE.

Comment: Do you host your site in IIS? If so, there is something to do in web.config if I remember correctly

Comment: When you leave a page the cache is gone. How do you use the cache?  Cachable HTTP calls are usually cached by the browser anyway.

Comment: Normally yes, but IE is IE... So there can be struggle coming from the server, that has to specify not to cache

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you have to set the headers `Cache-Control` and `If-Modified-Since` to get IE cache to work properly.